# c# how to using DIME soap request

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, .net-core, soap

Sorry in advance if I'm not clear enough, the topic is a bit new to me.
I use WCF - WSDL to attach a file to an endpoint.
I want to use DIME to attach a file
In order to use DIME I need a request soap context
I used soapUI to see the soap I need
I need help how to use this soap in order to use the DIME

Sample code

```
SoapContext reqContext = objCA SDM_WS.RequestSoapContext
DimeAttachment dimeAttach = New DimeAttachment("image/gif",
TypeFormat.MediaType, "c:\test.txt")
reqContext.Attachments.Add(dimeAttach)

strResult = SDM_WS.createAttachment(sid, "doc_rep:1002",
"cr:400001", "my desc", "c:\test.txt")
```

Sample soap

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://www.ca.com/UnicenterServicePlus/ServiceDesk">
                       <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <ser:createAttachment>
                                <sid>654741903</sid>
                                <repositoryHandle>doc_rep:1002</repositoryHandle>
                                <objectHandle>cr:635354</objectHandle>
                                <description>TEST</description>
                                <fileName>TEST</fileName>
                             </ser:createAttachment>
                          </soapenv:Body>
                       </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You can take a look at [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/december/sending-files-attachments-and-soap-messages-via-dime) which gives an example and suggestions.

Comment: I read the docs, it helped to understand a little more about DIME but I still could not understand how I implement the RequestSoapContext - WSE2